# Web API Custom Error Logging

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api

The goal of our application was to use the same custom logging we created for our ASP.NET MVC applications. We implemented a solution that used some of the techniques in ElmahExceptionLogger:

WebApiApplication (Global.asax.cs)

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var serializerSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    var contractResolver = (DefaultContractResolver)serializerSettings.ContractResolver;

    contractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new CustomExceptionLogger());
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new TokenAuthenticationAttribute());
}
```

CustomExceptionLogger

```
/// <summary>
/// Modified from ELMAH, 
/// URL: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/Elmah/Elmah.Server/ExceptionHandling/ElmahExceptionLogger.cs
/// </summary>
public class CustomExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    private const string HttpContextBaseKey = "MS_HttpContext";

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = GetHttpContext(context.Request); // Retrieve the current HttpContext instance for this request.
        NameValueCollection serverVariables = new NameValueCollection();

        LogException logException = new LogException();

        try
        {
            if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Request != null && httpContext.Request.ServerVariables != null)
                serverVariables = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables;

            logException.Log(context.Exception, serverVariables);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // swallow error because writing to log is failing
        }
    }
    private static HttpContext GetHttpContext(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpContextBase contextBase = GetHttpContextBase(request);

        if (contextBase == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return ToHttpContext(contextBase);
    }

    private static HttpContextBase GetHttpContextBase(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        object value;

        if (!request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpContextBaseKey, out value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value as HttpContextBase;
    }

    private static HttpContext ToHttpContext(HttpContextBase contextBase)
    {
        return contextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context;
    }
}
```

LogException

```
public class LogException
{
    public bool Log(Exception exception, NameValueCollection serverVariables)
    {
        var logService = new LogService();
        int loop1, loop2;
        StringBuilder serverVariableKeys = new StringBuilder();
        bool logged = false;

        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            // Get names of all keys into a string array
            string[] allKeys = serverVariables.AllKeys;

            for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < allKeys.Length; loop1++)
            {
                if (allKeys[loop1].ToUpper() != "ALL_HTTP" && allKeys[loop1].ToUpper() != "ALL_RAW")
                {
                    serverVariableKeys.Append(allKeys[loop1] + " : ");

                    string[] values = serverVariables.GetValues(allKeys[loop1]);

                    for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < values.Length; loop2++)
                    {
                        serverVariableKeys.AppendLine("Value " + loop2 + ": " + values[loop2]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (exception != null)
        {
            exception.Data.Add("ServerVariables", serverVariableKeys.ToString());
            logged = logService.LogException(exception, exception.TargetSite.Name);
        }

        return logged;
    }
}
```

I haven't include LogService source because this is specific to where it gets logged to, which can be a database or text file.

Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Regarding your opening statement **"The goal of our application was to use the same custom logging we created for our ASP.NET MVC applications."**. Could you clarify what kind of application you're trying to move the logging to? (console, web, etc.)

Comment: We use the LogException class in our ASP.NET MVC apps. This logic is part of a Web API application.

Comment: Okay. Got it! One more question, MVC 5, correct?

Comment: Correct. We are holding off on Core until it is a bit more feature rich, I'm guessing v2 of Core.

Comment: Just a quick look... Any big reason why your `CustomExceptionLogger` is derived from `ExceptionLogger` rather than using `IExceptionLogger`? I feel that using the interface would give you more mileage overall.

Comment: The IExceptionLogger requires that we implement LogAsync, which we didn't need. But you're right, it is a better practice to implement an interface in general.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my suggestions on your code.

**CustomExceptionLogger**

1. The constructor call for the `serverVariables` can be removed, since it is not used at all.
2. The empty `catch` statement gives a warning in Visual Studio, so I used a `private static void SwallowException(Exception ex)` to avoid having the warning.
3. In `GetHttpContextBase`, the two `if` can be combined in one.

In regards to #2, this might seem as an overkill for a totally harmless warning. I think it is important because if we leave these harmless warnings to appear, they can hide a warning that we would like to see.

```
public class CustomExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    private const string HttpContextBaseKey = "MS_HttpContext";

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = GetHttpContext(context.Request); // Retrieve the current HttpContext instance for this request.
        NameValueCollection serverVariables = null;

        LogException logException = new LogException();

        try
        {
            if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Request != null && httpContext.Request.ServerVariables != null)
                serverVariables = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables;

            logException.Log(context.Exception, serverVariables);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SwallowException(e);
        }
    }

    private static HttpContext GetHttpContext(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpContextBase contextBase = GetHttpContextBase(request);

        if (contextBase == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return ToHttpContext(contextBase);
    }

    private static HttpContextBase GetHttpContextBase(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        object value;

        if (request == null || !request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpContextBaseKey, out value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value as HttpContextBase;
    }

    private static HttpContext ToHttpContext(HttpContextBase contextBase)
    {
        return contextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context;
    }

    private static void SwallowException(Exception ex)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

**LogException**

1. The processing of the server variables should be in its own function. That can improve the readability of the `Log(..)` function.
2. In the `AppendServerVariables` (the new function), having `foreach` statements rather than `for` loops can reduce code and slightly improve speed; for example `allKeys[loop1]` is making a lookup every time it is used, while in the `foreach` you get a reference to it by default.
3. Also, the comparison that uses `ToUpper()` can be replaced with the use of `Equals` and `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` [which is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694903/2851870).

Also, one would suggest that when calling `.AppendLine(...)` you could use `string.Format(...)` but for such small strings, concatenation is faster.

Regarding the check for `HttpContext.Current` if is `null` I assumed that exists to ensure that the `serverVariables` has a value. That can be replaced by checking the `serverVariables` variable directly.

```
public class LogException
{
    public bool Log(Exception exception, NameValueCollection serverVariables = null)
    {
        var logService = new LogService();

        if (serverVariables != null)
        {
            AppendServerVariables(exception, serverVariables);
        }

        return logService.LogException(exception, exception.TargetSite.Name);
    }

    private void AppendServerVariables(Exception exception, NameValueCollection serverVariables)
    {
        StringBuilder serverVariableKeys = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string key in serverVariables.AllKeys)
        {
            if (!key.Equals("ALL_HTTP", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !key.Equals("ALL_RAW", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                serverVariableKeys.Append(key + " : ");

                int index = 0;
                string[] values = serverVariables.GetValues(key);
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                    serverVariableKeys.AppendLine("Value " + index.ToString() + ": " + value);
                    index += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        exception.Data.Add("ServerVariables", serverVariableKeys.ToString());
    }
}
```